# Pulling text from database with color

Tags: python, database, colorama

I'm writing a short interactive CLI game in python. I figured out how to pull text form my database, I have also figured out how to change color of the text. but I cant seem to get the two to work together.

`typewriter(Fore.RED + "Please press any key to enter the WhiteArchive")`
works just fine.

`typewriter(DB_Main.part1)` also works just fine.

`typewriter(Fore.RED + DB_Main.part1)` does not

Having kind of a rough time trying to find and figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It's `Fore.RED`, not `Fore.red`. Capitalization matters in Python.

Comment: @MattDMo Changed to Fore.RED and still did not work.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the output differ from the expected output? Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Does `typewriter(Fore.RED + str(DB_Main.part1))` work?